# PHP MYSQLI login Allow capital letter

Tags: php, authentication

This script does work, but if I use a capital letter for the user it does not work,

In the database is the user name Tom.
And I can login if i use Tom,
But tom does not work.
How can I fix it?

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$login=$_POST['login'];
if(isset($login)){
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Tech112!", "ripper");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }
  $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM login where username='$username' and password='$password'");
  $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
  $name = $row['name_login'];
  $user = $row['username'];
  $pass = $row['password'];
  $rank = $row['type_login'];
  if($user==$username && $pass=$password){
    session_start();
    if($rank=="2"){
      $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
      $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
      echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
    } else if($rank=="1"){
      $_SESSION['mysesi']=$user;
      $_SESSION['rank']=$rank;
      echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
    } 

    }
  } 
?>
```

Tom Lammers

Comment: Why u remove MYSQLI?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Convert both database and `$_POST` username to lowercase and compare those. This will make username case insensitive.

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM login where LOWER(`username`)='".strtolower($username)."' and password='$password'");
```

And edit your if to also compare with lowercase username.

```
if(strtolower($user) == strtolower($username) && $pass=$password){
```

**NB!** Your query is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to fix it.

To avoid SQL injection, use `bind_param`.

```
/* Code until query */

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where LOWER(`username`) = ? and password = ?");

// Add variables safely
$stmt->bind_param('ss', strtolower($username), $password);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

/* Rest of your code */
```

Comment: Ist not working, the username in the DB is Tom, but if I want to login with tom does not work

Comment: I edited my answer. You also have to edit your `if` statement to compare lowercased username.

Comment: Follow the link in my answer. Accepted answer has example for `MySQLi`,, basically you have to use `bind_param` function. Please accept my answer then.

Comment: Sorry, I had typo. change `$name` in `bind_param` to `$username`.